# Basic Django app index pathing syntax error

Tags: python, django

So I'm just getting started with Django and I decided to go through a tutorial that is a tad outdated in terms of syntax so I was wondering if someone could show me where I'm going wrong here and maybe provide a solution with the updated syntax :)

Thanks in advance!!

I'm running python 3.6 and Django 2.0.1 :)

Here is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZ5my3krEVM

skip forward to 13:10 for the syntax in question.

here is my code:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    path('', views.index, name='index')]
```

and here is my output:

```
   File "/home/jon/Py_Dev/venv/Django-Projects/mysite/webapp/urls.py", line 5
    path('', views.index, name='index')]
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're beginning urlpatterns with `{` but ending it with `]`.

Answer (score 1):

The opening  parenthesis should be a square bracket.

You have a `{` instead of a `[`:

```
urlpatterns = [                
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Comment: No, the problem is the opening bracket, which should be a `[`.

Comment: Yes.  I have changed it.